# Pandas: Filter DataFrame by two conditions

Tags: python, pandas

How do you filter a DataFrame if two conditions must apply in connection with not separately?
I tried to do this with a left outer join but I was wondering if there was a simpler approach:

```py
dataset = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "count": [2, 1, 1, 2, 1],
        "name": ["foo", None, "foo", None, "bar"],
    }
)
to_be_excluded = dataset.loc[(dataset["name"] == "foo") & (dataset["count"] == 1)]
pd.merge(
    dataset, to_be_excluded, on=["name", "count"], how="outer", indicator=True
).query('_merge=="left_only"').iloc[:, 0:2]
```

Expected:

```
count   name
2       foo
1       None
2       None
1       bar
```

Comment: Can you explain expected ouput?

Comment: Basically both conditions must apply. I'm trying to only filter out the records where name is "foo" and count is 1. Meaning, if name is "foo" but the count is higher, the record shouldn't be excluded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need `|` for bitwise `OR` with invert mask by `!=`:

```
df = dataset.loc[
    ((dataset["name"] != "foo") | (dataset["count"] != 1))
]
print (df)
   count  name
0      2   foo
1      1  None
3      2  None
4      1   bar
```

With your conditions invert mask by `~`:

```
df = dataset.loc[
    ~((dataset["name"] == "foo") & (dataset["count"] == 1))
]
print (df)
   count  name
0      2   foo
1      1  None
3      2  None
4      1   bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the & operator to apply both conditions together:

```
dataset.loc[((dataset["name"] != "foo") | (dataset["name"].isna())) & (dataset["count"] < 2)]
```

Note that `&` is the operator for "and", so the conditions inside the `loc` statement must be both `True` for a row to be included. Also, to handle both the `None` value and the string `"foo"`, we use the `|` operator for "or" and check for either `dataset["name"] != "foo"` or `dataset["name"].isna()`.